# EJB 3 timers executed multiple times

Tags: timer, ejb-3.1

I have some issues with my EJB 3 timer where it is launched more than once.
Rather than configuring the timer in an annotation, I use programmatic configuration, as explain in many blogs. Here's my code:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class AutoAssignTask extends AbstractDirectoryMonitor {

    @Resource
    private TimerService timer;

    @Inject
    @PropertyResource(name = "timer.hour", resource = "/DL4/app.conf")
    private String hour;
    @Inject
    @PropertyResource(name = "timer.minute", resource = "/DL4/app.conf")
    private String minute;
    @Inject
    @PropertyResource(name = "timer.second", resource = "/DL4/app.conf")
    private String second;

    @EJB
    private AutoAssignService autoAssignService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
            // initializing with an expression.
        this.initSchedule();
    }
    protected void initSchedule() {
        ScheduleExpression exp = new ScheduleExpression();
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.getHour())) {
            exp.hour(this.getHour());
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.getMinute())) {
            exp.minute(this.getMinute());
        }
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(this.getSecond())) {
            exp.second(this.getSecond());
        }
        this.getTimer().createCalendarTimer(exp);
    }

    @Timeout
    public void process() {
        // do something
        AutoAssignTask.LOG.info("starting job.");
    }
```

Now let's say I configure the timer for every minute, when I look at my logs I get twice the "starting job" log, proving it starts the job twice.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: This is EJB 3.1 code, not 3.0 - changed tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. Update the code to show the `initSchedule()` method.  The problem could be in the `ScheduleExpression`.
2. You never can rule out server bugs.  Check to make sure your @PostConstruct is not called twice which would happen if your server created two singletons (common race condition issue).
3. As you have some sub-classing, make sure you're aware that if `AutoAssignTask` is further sub-classed the `@PostConstruct` of `AutoAssignTask` will still be called.  More simply put, the `@PostConstruct` method of an EJB's super classes are also invoked -- the oldest parent first.

For number 2 and 3, a simple static AtomicInteger and log statement would work:

```
public class AutoAssignTask extends AbstractDirectoryMonitor {

    private static final AtomicInteger instances = new AtomicInteger();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("AutoAssignTask instance "+instances.incrementAndGet());
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the leads.
I added the instances counter just to confirm that no timer is instantiated twice.
after restarting my GF service, I don't have the problem anymore. Weird since I restarted my server many times before posting here. It's true that at some point, I killed the Java process manually, and when the server restarted, GF reused the timers, having the timeout being launched twice. Reloading the application fixed everything.

I'll keep monitoring my servers and isolate the problem.

Comment: Of course, timer's are persistent by default.  I can't believe I missed that as a possible cause!  Thanks for the followup.  Note, you can change your timer to non-persistent if you want -- can be nice for development.

Comment: OK, we've spotted GlassFish behavior. When the server restarts, the existing monitor is persisted, therefore a new one is created. On the contrary, when you redeploy an application or reload it, the monitor is replaced.

Answer (score 5):

The question might be pretty old, but it looks (for **JBoss EAP 7** at least) , that timers are stored in `%JBOSS_HOME%\standalone\data\timer-service-data` in an XML format. So it is pretty likely that it reads from their multiple `ScheduleExpression`.

At least that was for my case. Deleting all the XML and redeploying the application solved the problem.

Comment: Deleting the content of the timer folder worked for me. It looks like JBoss adds a new timer every time I deploy the application. I had 53 timers at one time and the first one would start immediately after deployment had finished. The timers do not get removed when I redeploy or undeploy the application.

Comment: It looks like TimerService.createTimer() creates persisted timers and each deploy creates a new one. Two solutions worked for me.
1. Call TimerService.getAllTimers and cancel them before creating a new one.
2. Use TimerService.createIntervalTimer and set persistence to false.

Comment: I faced the same problem in Wildly 10.1.0. Deleting the XML files as suggested fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can add this when creating the timerService and pass it through the constructor :
final TimerConfig timerconf = new TimerConfig();
  timerconf.setPersistent(false);